# How do to have a template deduce its parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-deduction

I am trying to write a sink for a `back_inserter` to reduce the amount of `std::copy()` commands that proliferate the code.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename OutputIterator>
class sink
{
public:
    sink(OutputIterator out) : _out(out) { }
    OutputIterator _out;
};

template <typename OI, typename C>
sink<OI>& operator<<(sink<OI>& s, const C& c)
{
    std::copy(c.begin(), c.end(), s._out);
    return s;
}


int main(int, const char*[])
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> c;
//    auto s = sink<std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<uint8_t>>>(std::back_inserter(c));
    auto s = sink(std::back_inserter(c));

    s << std::vector<uint8_t>{'F','e','e','d','i','n','g',' ','f','r','o','g','g','i','e','s'};
    s << std::string("Hungry hippos");

    std::copy(c.begin(), c.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ":"));
}
```

However this gives the error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, const char**)':
main.cpp:27:18: error: missing template arguments before '(' token
     auto s = sink(std::back_inserter(c));
                  ^
```

The code below works but is less than desirable as it looks worse than having lots of `std::copy` function calls everywhere.

```
auto s = sink<std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<uint8_t>>>(std::back_inserter(c));
```

How do I give the hint to the compiler to deduce the type automatically?

Eventually I would like to evolve the system so I can simply write

```
sink(out) << reply::stock_reply(reply::bad_request);
```

where `out` is a `back_insert_iterator` and `stock_reply` gives a canned response.

Comment: Use C++17 if you can, which has added this exact feature: https://wandbox.org/permlink/RqYk2MohPJQdb72O Before that, C++ only allowed deduction of template arguments for function templates.

Comment: No can do.  I am limited to gcc4.8.4 by the platform I working on.

Comment: Then the usual solution is to use a function, like `make_shared` (turn the construction of a `sink` instance into a call of a function template returning some `sink_class` instance).

Comment: "Before that, C++ only allowed deduction of template arguments for function templates." That I didn't actually know. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++17 added this exact feature, along with surrounding help in cases where disambiguation is necessary. It's called [class template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction).

If that is not an option, you can resort to the workarounds such as "make" helper functions. This is what this would look like in your case (the `forward` is not strictly necessary for you here):

```
template<typename OutputIterator>
sink<std::decay_t<OutputIterator>> make_sink(OutputIterator&& output_iterator)
{
    return sink<std::decay_t<OutputIterator>>(std::forward<OutputIterator>(output_iterator));
}
```

[Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d7a4ecdfb4ebf80). The `std::decay_t` is so that the function does the right thing when passed an lvalue.

Comment: *"make them static in your class"* I don't see how OP can call it to deduce type... or you mean `sink<dummy>::make(std::back_inserter(c))` which seems ugly (because of the dummy type) ?

Comment: I got rid of that suggestion, it is indeed incorrect here.

Comment: You probably want `sink<decay_t<OutputIterator>>`, otherwise you're keeping a reference - so not really a sink.

Comment: @Barry the compiler disagrees with you: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/437a11c04a5e16fc. Your comment does seem to make sense, but it seems I'm not hitting the special case you're thinking of.

Comment: I will accept this even though @dyp gave the answer in the comment.

Comment: @rubenvb Pass in an lvalue instead of an rvalue.